# duplicate values in foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, woocommerce

I am trying to show some custom attributes in woocommerce.
Therefor I am echoing keys of an array.

```
    $mails = get_the_terms( $prod_id, 'pa_email');

    foreach ( $mails as $mail ) {
          $mmail=$mail->name;
    }
```

This works fine so far. But if an item does not have the mail address set, it gives out the last used value of the item before. I just want it to be empty then instead of duplicating the last value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ever heard of [isset](http://php.net/manual/it/function.isset.php) and [empty](http://php.net/manual/it/function.empty.php) in PHP?

```
$mails = get_the_terms( $prod_id, 'pa_email');

foreach ( $mails as $mail )
{
  if(!isset($mail->name) || empty($mail->name))
  {
    $mmail = "";
  }
  else
  { 
    $mmail=$mail->name;
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm, now as you mentioned it. But sadly that does not solve my issue. For some reasons it seems that the empty items does not return anything in the array. Nevermind, your answer is absolutely correct and this seems to be an issue with woocommerce.

Comment: @fourgood hmm whenever in doubt with a variable (like here) do a `var_dump` to see what's in it. Once you know what it's holding inside you can handle it accordingly. Feel free to attach the result of `var_dump` to your answer if you need further help.